# Is there a way in GraphDB to store reasoning results in different contexts?

Tags: rule-engine, graphdb

Is there a way in GraphDB 10.0.0 to safe the conclusions of different rules in different named graphs or contexts?
For example, if I have two rules like this:

```
id: rule1
     x a <:Article>
     y a <:Author>
     --------------------
     y <:mightWrite> x [Context: base_context:c1]

id: rule2
     x a <:Book>
     y a <:Author>
     --------------------
     y <:mightWrite> x [Context: base_context:c2]
```

Reasoning would lead to the results of both rules being stored within context `onto:implicit` instead of, what I would have expected, `base_context:c1` and `base_context:c2`. Thus, is there a way to do such splitting of the readoning results?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Simple answer is NO, altough the rule syntax allow for such constructs, these are used only to build functional relations that are implementation specific to aid building recursive rules that can handle chains and/or rdf lists.
look at https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/reasoning.html#rules section for more. In short any such conclusions, placed in a rule specific contexts are not visible and can be accessed/looked up only from rule premices that reffer to them.

HTH

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov thank you for your quick answer! That clarifies what I found in the documentation. Feel free to add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.